# Play, Eclipse, Java generate project template

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.2

I have a small problem with compiling default Play project to Eclipse template.
Im doing as it is written, in tutorial:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

This is my console output, it is step by step.

- Creating a project
- Running Play console

Running "eclipse" command.

```
C:\JAVA\Play>play new WareHouse
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2-RC3 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_45), http://www.playf
ramework.com

The new application will be created in C:\JAVA\Play\WareHouse

What is the application name? [WareHouse]
>

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

  1             - Create a simple Scala application
  2             - Create a simple Java application

> 2
OK, application WareHouse is created.

Have fun!


C:\JAVA\Play>play
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2-RC3 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_45), http://www.playf
ramework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`
.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.



C:\JAVA\Play>cd WareHouse

C:\JAVA\Play\WareHouse>play
[info] Loading project definition from C:\JAVA\Play\WareHouse\project
[info] Set current project to WareHouse (in build file:/C:/JAVA/Play/WareHouse/)

       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2-RC3 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.7.0_45), http://www.playf
ramework.com

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[WareHouse] $ eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Updating {file:/C:/JAVA/Play/WareHouse/}warehouse...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.0-GA ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#templates_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-file_2.10;0.4.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-core_2.10;0.4.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.jsuereth#scala-arm_2.10;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;0.7 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.3.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.7.0.Final ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.13 ...
  [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.13 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.2.0 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.10;2.2.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.7.18 ...
  [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
  [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
  [info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;14.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.172 ...
  [info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.12 ...
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;5.0.1.Final ...
  [info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final ...
  [info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.1.1.GA ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#classmate;0.8.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-context;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-core;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-beans;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections;0.9.8 ...
  [info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm;3.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Final ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.6 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
  [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;2.1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.10 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.8.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.8.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.12 ...
  [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
  [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.2.3 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.12 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.18 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.9 ...
  [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.2.2-RC3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.10;1.0.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\JAVA\Play\WareHouse\ta
rget\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near in
dex 22
[error] .*scala-library[^\].jar
[error]                       ^
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[WareHouse] $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are facing a bug specific to Play Framework **2.2.2-RC3** ([GitHub Issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2376)). I recommend a stable release such as as [Play Framework **2.2.1**](http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.2.1/play-2.2.1.zip).

Comment: Wow, thank You for your research :) I will switch to 2.2.1 and inform will it help.