# Problems installing Play framework on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, playframework

I am trying to install the Play! framework onto my OSX Mavericks laptop. Everything installs and works fine using the default install paths until I try to convert a new application to an eclipse project. I can convert Scala projects just fine. But when I try to convert a Java application to an eclipse project I get the following error from the Play! console:

```
 [TestAppOne] $ eclipse
 [info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
 [info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/mcd/play/TestAppOne/target/scala-2.10/classes...
 [error] could not find scala-library.jar
 [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I can see the scala-library.jar (2.10.3) and I even added it to /etc/paths; no luck. I am using Java 1.7 and Kepler eclipse and Play 2.2.2-RC3. Any suggestions to help convert the Play! project to eclipse?

Comment: Never seen that error before. Could you post your build.sbt file? What does running 'play compile' do?

Comment: I am using the binary distribution. I am not building Play. That is why I am not sure of the fix. There seems to be a broken dependency in the released binary that I downloaded (2.2.2-RC3).

Comment: I tried "play compile"; it worked and returned [success]. My project conversion to an eclipse project still fails, however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play, Eclipse, Java generate project template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798391/play-eclipse-java-generate-project-template)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove everything redundant from path, leave only java and play home (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Installing) there and "replay" your project

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason that you are using RC instead of stable release?

Play 2.2.2-RC3 has reported issue about this problem 3 days ago, check on [Github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2376) or similar question posted few hours ago on the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21798391/1066240)

(FYI, just tested: sample Play 2.2.1 project *eclipsied* on Mavericks without any problem, unfortunately I have no Eclipse installed, but assume, that there should not be any problems to open it there, Idea works like a charm)

Comment: When I looked at the list of available downloads, there was 2.2.2-RC# and a long list of 1.xx. When I look more closely, I see that there is a wide-array of versions. Is there a reason this list is not sorted? Anyway; I hunted up 2.2.1 and it works fine. Thank you for your help. Now, to play with Play!